# AFNetworking 2.0 valid certificate, still no connection (error 1012)

Tags: validation, ssl, ssl-certificate, nsurlconnection, afnetworking-2

This is my first post, and I hope you guys can help me.

What is the problem?
When I was developing my app I used an unencrypted connection (because I had no valid and trusted certificate) so it worked all the time. Now is the app almost done, and I want to use a encrypted connection. I bought a valid certificate for my server and it is working as it should be, when I go in my browser to my server it says that is has a valid and trusted certificate. But, when I change the server url in my app, I get the error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)".

I searched the internet, but I found most of the time problems with a self-signed certificate, and they had to set *allowInvalidCertificates* to true. Ofcourse, I don't want to set this option to true, it has to be false. Also the pinning option is set to None, so actually I dont understand why the app can't connect to my server while it is using a valid certificate.

I hope some of you can help me!

[update]
When I change the *allowInvalidCertificates* to true, it works. So I think it has something to do with the verification of the certificate. When I'm browsing in the simulator with safari to the server-url it just opens as it should. No warnings or errors.

Thanks, Joey

Comment: Same problem here, importing own cert and still no luck. Also tried adding root certificate. Using AFNetworking 2.2.2 (lastest at time)

Comment: Hi @webo80 I suggest you to check my answer ;)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, got it!

First I checked the status of my ssl-server at: http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Then I saw that there was something wrong. The certificate was not trusted by all major web browsers.. So, I had to add the CA-bundle on my server en then tada! All tests passed.

I checked directly my connection with the app and yes, it worked immediately :)

Maybe some of you guys have the same situation, and this could be your answer :) Good luck!

Cheers, Joey

Comment: Thanks a lot ! After lots of hours of search on google, this is the first good response i found !